# How to access indexDb varible and access that varible?

Tags: javascript, async-await, indexeddb

Need to use async/await for fetching all values from IndexDb
// expecting b to have result-set from index-db

```
var b ="";
var request = window.indexedDB.open("mydb");
request.onsuccess = function (event) {
 var db = event.target.result;
 var objectStore = db.transaction("mytable").objectStore("mytable");
 allRecords =   objectStore.getAll();
 allRecords.onsuccess=  function(event){
   console.log(event.target.result)
    b = 10;
    b = event.target.result

 }
 console.log(b);
 //b is ""
```

Comment: You need to learn about asynchronous programming before using indexedDB.

Answer (score 0):

```
var promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
   var request = window.indexedDB.open("mydb");
   request.onsuccess = function (event) {
    var db = event.target.result;
    var objectStore = db.transaction("mytable").objectStore("mytable");
    allRecords =   objectStore.getAll();
    allRecords.onsuccess=  function(event){
      console.log(event.target.result)
       b = 10;
       b = event.target.result

    }

}
promise.then((a)=>console.log(a));
```